Return the most similar string from list
Given the query "Belem Tower" and this list of strings: "Belem", "Belem Tower, Lisbon, Portugal", how can I create a function in PHP which returns the string in the list that is most similar to the query.
In this example, the output should be "Belem Tower, Lisbon, Portugal".
I've tried fiddling around with similar_text() and levenshtein() but I can't get either to return the result I'm looking for.

similar text() method is better than levenshteirn. Good libe

Can you show us your failed implementations so we can understand why they didn't work for you?

Is your desired result attained if you remove the cost of character deletions? https://3v4l.org/EGI13  Perhaps we need to a clearer indication of what success should look like. @user  Can you provide 3 or 4 completely separate scenarios so that we can better test different algorithm settings?

Since similar_text returns how similar two strings are and levenshtein returns the minimum number of single-character edits needed to transform one string into another, similar_text will be the one to act more like a search mechanism:
function findMostSimilarString($query, $strings) {
$maxSimilarity = 0;
$mostSimilarString = '';

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $similarity = similar_text($query, $string);

    if ($similarity > $maxSimilarity) {
        $maxSimilarity = $similarity;
        $mostSimilarString = $string;
    }
}

return $mostSimilarString;

}
This will return the first string with the highest similarity relative to the query

This is a chatgpt answer. I've already tried this and it returns the wrong result.

Sorry, there was a mistake on the way similar_text was called, try it now
